# При загрузке файлов, получить содержимое

Tags: php

Используя форму я хочу загрузить несколько текстовых файлов, получить и сохранить содержимое каждого.

Форма:

```
<form name="form" method="post">
<input type="file" class="my" id="myfile" name="file_content" multiple="multiple"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="отправить">
```

PHP:

```
    $len = count($_FILES['file_content']['tmp_name']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $post_title = $_FILES['file_content']['name'][$i];
        $post_content = $_FILES['file_content']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $post_content = file_get_contents($post_content);
     }
```

Вроде все правильно, но выдает ошибку "file_get_contents(C): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Спасибо.

Comment: Нет, все неправильно. Посмотри в мануале как делать загрузку файлов

Comment: Уже раз 10 перечитал мануал. Проблема в том, что у других людей тот же код работает как надо, а у меня - нет.

Comment: Этот код вообще ни у кого не работает. Форма делана совершенно неправильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все очень просто!

Все дело было в

```
<input type="file" class="my" id="myfile" name="file_content" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Обязательно name должен содержать "[]", то есть при  `name="file_content[]"`
все работает.

Answer (score -1):

Примерно так. По идее хорошо-бы проверять расширение, mime-тип, содржимое файлов перед сохранением.

```
$uploadDir = "files/"; 
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_content']['name']); $i++) { 
    $uploadFile[$i] = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['file_content']['name'][$i]);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_content']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadFile[$i])) {
        echo "Успешно загружен <br>";
    } else {
    echo "Ошибка ".$_FILES['file_content']['error'][$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код бесполезен для автора вопроса, поскольку его проблема совсем в другом, а перемещать файлы куда-либо ему не нужно вообще. Также этот код скорее вреден для других читателей, поскольку проверку поля 'error' надо делать ДО попытки переместить файл, а  echo "Ошибка " - это НЕ то как следует обрабатывать ошибки в РНР.